# Python - to put space after period; not for a decimal number

Tags: python, regex, decimal, space, period

Using Python and regex, would you please help converting

```
First sentence.Second sentence. Third 3.4 sentence3.Fourth sentence. Fifth5. Sixth.
```

to

```
First sentence. Second sentence. Third 3.4 sentence3. Fourth sentence. Fifth5. Sixth.
```

i.e., space needs to be inserted when it is between two alphabets and either one of the characters on either side is an alphabet. Space need NOT be inserted if both sides of the period is a digit. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. Questions here are expected to be *specific*, ideally relating to an actual existing attempt to write the code. The first thing you need to do (and *you* need to do it) is figure out the objective rules - what is "an alphabet"? The second thing is to try to write that code, for example starting by looking up the regex documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead assertion to make sure there is no white space, `$`, or any digits after the period.
You can use `re.sub` to substitute such occurrences of period with space after period.

```py
>>> import re
>>> text = 'First sentence.Second sentence. Third 3.4 sentence3.Fourth sentence. Fifth5. Sixth.'
>>> re.sub('\.(?!\s|\d|$)', '. ', text)
'First sentence. Second sentence. Third 3.4 sentence3. Fourth sentence. Fifth5. Sixth.'
```

Comment: What about acronyms, such as `A.C.E.` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, to include acronym, the regex needs modification. As it was not explicitly mentioned in the question, I did not think about  it.